# Amazon Beanstalk deploy not including submodules

Tags: php, wordpress, git, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using this [wordpress skeleton](https://github.com/markjaquith/WordPress-Skeleton) locally and have an issue getting it to work on AWS Beanstalk. When I open /index.php I am seeing a blank page in the browser and the following message in the logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required './wp/wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/app/current/index.php on line 4
```

The location **./wp/wp-blog-header.php** relative to file index.php exists, but php on beanstalk is unable to find it. When I change it to **wp/wp-blog-header.php** its not working either.

**Update**

It turns out the command `eb deploy` is not pushing submodules and my setup is using a submodule. So the files are actually not there because they are in a submodule. Is there a way to make this happen? I am using [awsebcli 3.1.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/awsebcli).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.ebextensions config](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html) to run any commands. Also for modules install/deploy.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me using EB CLI 3.x. Do you have that working with the new version of the CLI?

Comment: Yes, it works for me. What's exactly the problem in your case?